# send user defined object as an argument and stored in an array and obtain desired value

Tags: javascript

here a `book` constructor function creates instance of books and `person` constructor creates new author instance.then the instace created by person was sent as parameter to book constructor function and stored in an array using **this.author**..but i am having hard time to alert the value of the author full name for story book instance.how can i get the value that i desire.and as i have sent an object instance to another constructor function ,so how this keyword will be manipulated.i mean 
this.author has an object whis has two properties this.firstname and this.lastname

so i can say `this.author>[{this.lastname;this.firstname}]`
so how can i alert a value from a mess of `this.`??

**code**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function Person(lastname,firstname){
  this.lastname=lastname;
  this.firstname=firstname;
}
var mrX=new Person("X","mr");

function Book(name,price,page){
    this.name=name;
    this.price=price;
    this.page=page;
    this.author=new Array(arguments.length-3);
    for(i=0;i<arguments.length-3;i++){
        this.author[i]=arguments[i+3];

    }
}
var storyBook=new Book('vuter golpo','200','60',mrX);
alert(this.author.firstname);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw, you should use [`for (var i=0; …`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.author` property of the books contains an array. You will need to use `storyBook.author[0].firstName` and `storyBook.author[0].lastName` - as `storyBook.author[0] === mrX`.

You can't use `this` to get the `storyBook` instance, the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is meaningful only in methods and constructors.